# Extract label from hostname in Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala

We know that a [hostname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) is dot-separated labels. Now I've written a function to return either the first or second label as follows:

```
private def title(hostname: String) = hostname.split('.') match {
  case Array("www", label, _*) if !label.isEmpty => label
  case Array(label, _*) if !label.isEmpty => label
  case _ => hostname
}
```

Can it be simplified ? Can it be replaced with a nice and simple regular expression ?

Comment: I doubt regex will be simpler. Considering the hostname could have any number of dots `.` in it, using a `.split('.')` is definitely the way to go here. [This is shortest, nicest regex I can think of](http://regex101.com/r/bN4zO5/1) but splitting is probably the best choice

Comment: I would also stick with the split approach, as somebody said: "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live."

Comment: also note the existence of `_.nonEmpty`

Comment: @RobStarling Thanks. I've forgotten about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Here's a oneliner that achieves the same result:

```
private def title(hostname: String) =
 hostname.stripPrefix("www.").split('.').filter(_.nonEmpty).headOption.getOrElse(hostname)
```

I think it's pretty clear to read.

A few examples:

```
scala> title("www.google.com")
res21: String = google

scala> title("google.com")
res22: String = google

scala> title("www.")
res23: String = www.
```

---

Here's a regex solution instead

```
private def title(hostname: String): String = {
  val p = "(?:www\\.)?(\\w+)".r
  (p findAllIn hostname).matchData collectFirst {
    case m => m.group(1)
  } getOrElse hostname
}
```

Example

```
scala> title("www.google.com")
res1: String = google

scala> title("google.com")
res2: String = google
```

That being said, If I were your coworker I would much appreciate your first version, rather than mine.

Comment: but I think it didn't work in case of subdomain `www.help.yahoo.com`

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti it returns `"help"`, which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Thanks. I like the oneliner !

Comment: The regex solution is `val p = "(?:www\\.)?(\\w+)".r.unanchored` and `def f(s: String) = s match { case p(x) => x case x => x }`, which is as clear as it gets, modulo tweaking the pattern.